# Download File From DropBox - Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to write an app in Android that when requested will download a specific file from DropBox if the file is available.

I have gone through all of the tutorials in the developer section on the DropBox site but I don't think they are really detailed enough as each of the tutorials seem to have bits missing and I haven't been able to get any of them to fully work.

I have tried examples of both uploading/downloading files from the tutorials but each time I get to this part of my code I get Exception errors.  This leads me to believe that I have missed something out so I was wondering whether there was a decent tutorial anywhere that properly explains the process of downloading a specific file (rather than bringing up DropBox for the user to select the file) from dropBox so that I can follow it through and hopefully will help me to understand where I am currently going wrong.

I know there are lots of questions similar to this but most of them state that they can get part of the process to work and need help on a particular part but I don't seem to be able to get anything to work other than the actual linking to my DropBox account (I have created a DropBox app and have added the keys etc. to my software).

If anyone can help point me in the direction of a decent tutorial that properly explains this process I would be grateful.

Thanks...

I thought I should expand on my issue which hopefully will help to identify the problem that I am having.

The main tutorial I am using at the moment is: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android

I have created an app in the App Console which allows file sharing; this has also given my key and secret code.

I have downloaded and installed the mentioned SDK and have added it to my project; I know this works as without the SDK installed most of the code produces errors.

I have added the beginning part of this tutorial which sets up the authorization to DropBox from my app; this works as when I test it I am taken to a page on my device that requests that I select the correct DropBox account.  Up to this part I have no issues with and it all seems to work.

The next part of the tutorial mentions uploading/downloading files and reading the directory structure.  I have tested all of these separately but for each one I get an Exception error; the errors seem to mention something called "json" and a class not being found.  The tutorial does not mention needing to install another SDK or any other library files so I am unsure whether it is assuming that something has already been done which I have not known about so hasn't been done.

I hope this makes sense and would appreciate any help you can give me...

Comment: What is the exception? stack trace in logcat?

Comment: The most recent Exception I am getting in my current code is:  Could not find class 'org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser', referenced from method com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.parseAsJSON

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is related with JSON library you used to connect with Dropbox server. here is the libraries list I used for my application, it works well and can download the file to cache.

1. dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar
2. dropbox-core-sdk-1.7.7.jar
3. jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
4. jackson-core-2.2.4.jar
5. jackson-databind-2.2.4.jar

The library jars in the dropbox-java-sdk-1.7.7 package are not enough.